# ¿Por que metira este error si la Google Api esta configurada?

Tags: react-native, google-maps, google-api, expo

Estuve programando en React Expo y utilizando Google Api Places pero sucede algo extraño...

Utilice la libreria de react-native-google-places-autocomplete por una cuestiòn de que me parecia mas comodo, por lo tanto quedo asi:

```
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
    placeholder="Buscar Direccion"
    query={{
      key: "key_Value",
      language: 'es',
    }}
    onPress={(data, details = null) => console.log(data)}
    onFail={(error) => console.error(error)}
  />
```

Lo que hice en mi google Api fue configurar las direcciones de sitio web con las direcciones que me daba Expo, de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Ahora cual es el problema?
Hay veces que me da el error " ERROR  API keys with referer restrictions cannot be used with this API. " y otras veces no... Es como que sucede de forma aleatoria.

Supongamos que escriba Calle Falsa 123, a medida de que voy escribiendo este me da un listado pero a medida que voy tipeando aparece el error.

Si escribo "Call" aparece el error pero si le agrego la "e" me filtra las calles, por lo tanto este error sucede de forma aleatoria y es bastante molesto, son mas las veces que no funciona que las que funciona y me imposibilita testear la app correctamente.

¿A que se debe este problema?
Esto sucede al abrirlo en un Android ya que estoy programando una app.